# AngularJS: using $http interceptors and OAuth tokens when using ng-src directive

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cordova, oauth

I am building a Cordova/Phonegap app that interacts with a Rails server through a JSON API that uses OAuth.

I already have lots of button-driven functionality working and I am using a http interceptor for catching `401 Unauthorized` server responses that requests new OAuth tokens and then retries the same request.

My solution is essentially based on this code: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

But I do not see how to do all this while getting images through `<img ng-src="image/url">`.

So my question is two-fold:

1- How do I inject the OAuth token in the `ng-src` request?

2- How do I intercept the 401 responses for updating the authorization token and retry the requests?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but this is a great tutorial that may help https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/

Comment: Thank you @PaulFitzgerald. That sure looks like one great tutorial, but it does not quite help me with this specific problem. I am specifically looking at how to implement OAuth security when using the `ng-src` directive. On top of that, how to intercept the server responses, just like when using plain `$http` requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vasco! How are you?

I used an approach similar to the one used in this link:
https://github.com/dougmoscrop/angular-img-http-src/blob/master/index.js

I added parts of this to my controller:

```
function SampleCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.ImageUrl = '';

    // this method can be on a service ($http or $resource)
    $scope.getImageService = function (imageId) {
        return $http.get('../MyApi/MyAction/', {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            params: { id: imageId }
        });
    };

    // this will be called when you need to load the image
    $scope.loadImage = function(imageId)
    {
        $scope.getImageService(imageId).then(function (response) {
            var imageBlob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.headers('Content-Type') });
            $scope.ImageUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(imageBlob);
        });
    };

    $scope.loadImage('image_001');
}
```

And the html will look like:

```
<img ng-src="{{ImageUrl}}" alt="alternate" title="title" />
```

Doing that, the interceptor will handle the http get and include the header with the OAuth token.

Answer (score 0):

To answer both questions, what you need is a http interceptor that will 1) Set the Oauth token into all out going requests, and 2) Catch 401 errors and resolve them for you, refreshing and setting authentication tokens if and when necessary.

Check out this [excellent post](http://engineering.talis.com/articles/elegant-api-auth-angular-js/) on how to do so. Also read the insightful AngularJs documentation on [$http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). All is there.

I really hope these help you. Best.